# SQL add comma seperators on an integer value

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I have a query:

```
select sum(invoiceamount) as invoice
from fact_salescount
where year in ({YEAR})
and month >= ({FROMMONTH})
and month <= ({TOMONTH})
```

This query can return a value from 100.00 to 15034115.93. It will return ONE value.
I would like to add, for each 000, like this: 15,034,115.93

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but none match mine. I hope someone can help me out.

I am using Pentaho and MySQL, and creating these queries within the Design Studio.

Comment: I think formatting numbers should be done in the frontend.

Comment: Add `group by year` at the end of query

Comment: Does Pentaho use a more common database as a backend or does it act as a RDBMS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried your answer Lieven, but it does not work. Also it seems as if MySQL does not reconize the style 'money'?

Comment: You didn't specify you use MySQL.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598879/thousands-separator-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(sum(invoiceamount),2)
FROM fact_salescount
WHERE year IN ({YEAR})
AND month >= ({FROMMONTH})
AND month <= ({TOMONTH})
```

This should do what you want, but I still don't like formatting number in the backend.

Comment: This is indeed what I wanted. Works! I am not formatting it in the database, but formatting it within an .xaction. Struggling alot with Pentaho :).