# Thousands separator in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my MySQL database (ex. salary). Datatype is `DECIMAL(8,2)`. I noticed that it doesn't have a *thousand separator*.

How would I select the whole column and put a thousands separator in each record?

Comment: How is the data inserted? If with PHP you could use php number_format().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the help of the [Format Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) in this way :

```
SELECT FORMAT(col_name, 2) FROM table;
```

You can also specify a locale(for example italian) :

```
SELECT FORMAT(col_name, 2, 'it_IT') FROM table;
```

Comment: thanks! I was able to view records with thousands separator but how do I permanently put thousands separator in the values on the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the data with:

```
SELECT FORMAT(col, num_of_decimals)
```

Comment: What's different from my answer ?

Comment: I don't think so, i answered 3 minutes before ... You commented before the question but with a different approach to the solution.

Comment: Yes, then i remembered FORMAT() and began to answer, and wasnt sure about the actual format so i googled it. Wrote it and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. You should store the number without the thousands-comma formatting, and save this type of number formatting for the output query. This would be like trying to store numbers with font formatting. Wrong reason to try it, and wrong place to store it.

The reason is that you want the database to store data in a way that databases are designed to operate, e.g. making calculations, comparisons, etc. Otherwise you're basically storing numbers as strings, which defeats the purpose of storing them as numbers.